# Simple calculation resulting in 0

Tags: c++

I cant count the number of times i get strange results from otherwise simple calculations. In this simple program I'm trying to calculate the chances of derangements as seen from this numberphile vid (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbXg5EI5t4c), however near the end of my main I keep getting my total percentage

```
<< "total: " << static_cast<double>(matches / (matches + mismatch) * 100) << endl;
```

always resulting in a 0 regardless of what the values are. Thanks in advance and any help is appreciated.

my whole code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void Fill(int[], int);
void Randomize(int[], int const);

int main()
{
    int  amount = 10, //size of array sample size
         runs = 1,     //how many test runs
         matches = 0,  //how many times each shuffle has 1 match
         mismatch = 0; //how many times each shuffle has no matches
    bool match;
    unsigned seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);

    int cards[10];
    Fill(cards, amount); //fills array to desired ammount

    do
    {
       cout << "runs: ";
       cin >> runs;
       for(int i = runs; i > 0; i--)
       {

            Randomize(cards, ammount);        //shuffle
            for (int i = 0; i < ammount; i++)
            {
                if (cards[i] == i)
                {
                    match = true;
                    break;
                }
                else match = 0;
            }
            if (match)
            matches++;
            else
            mismatch++;

       }
       cout << "matches: " << matches << endl 
            << "mismatches: " << mismatch << endl
            << "total: " << static_cast<double>(matches / (matches + mismatch) * 100) << endl;
    }while (runs != 0);


    return 0;
}

void Fill(int arr[], int size)
{
     for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
             arr[i] = i;
     }
}

void Randomize(int a1[], int const size)
{
     int a2[10];
     int c = 0;
     for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
         c = (rand() % (size - i));
         a2[i] = a1[c];
         a1[c] = a1[size - i - 1];   
     }
     for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){a1[i] = a2[i];}   
}
```

Comment: `matches / (matches + mismatch)` is an integer division, thus the result is truncated to an integer. To make the divison floating-point, you need at least one operand to be floating-point. The simplest way would be `foo / double(bar)`.

Comment: Also, if you use `C++11` or any other version-specific C++ tag, you should always include `C++` itself for convenience. I edited this for you.

Comment: Also, this was already answered here: [What is the behavior of integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division)

Comment: Sooner or later, you should really take a look at what [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota), [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) and [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) can offer to you.

Answer (score 1):

In this statement, the `static_cast` is applied **after** the calculation is done.

```
static_cast<double>(matches / (matches + mismatch) * 100)
```

So what the program *actually* does is do the calculation in `int`, then convert to `double`, and you're getting `0.0` because the result of the integer arithmetic is zero.

To fix, manually cast at least one value to `double`:

```
(1.0 * matches / (matches + mismatch) * 100)
 ^^^
(double(matches) / (matches + mismatch) * 100)
 ^^^^^^^       ^
```

Answer (score -1):

The integer division does that. To prevent it, cast the value either explicitly or implicitly, e.g.

```
<< "total: " << (100.0 * matches / (matches + mismatch)) << endl;
```